# Weird error when running code with sublime

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimetext

When I want to run (command + B) any code with the sublime text editor, I get following error:

```
[WinError 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
[cmd: ['py', '-u', 'C:\\Users\\XXX\\Documents\\coding\\pygame\\spaceinvaders\\main.py']]
[dir: C:\Users\Leander\Documents\coding\pygame\spaceinvaders]
[path: C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\Leander\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;%DASHLANE_DLL_DIR%;;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.3\bin;]
[Finished]
```

I tried:

```
print("hello")
```

and got the same result.
When I run it with the cmd:

```
python C:\Users\XXX\Documents\coding\pygame\spaceinvaders\main.py
```

it works just fine. I made sure i checked Python at "Tools" > "Build System", but same result...

Comment: What happens if you manually run the command `py -u C:\Users\XXX\Documents\coding\pygame\spaceinvaders\main.py`?

Comment: The default build system in ST4 won't work for you if you use a Python distribution that doesn't include the `py` helper (Miniconda does not, for example). It looks like you may be using the Python that comes with Pycharm to execute your code, which would also not have set that up.

Comment: when i run the command it tells me that "py" is not a known command. So what do I have to do to make it work? Install an other version of python?

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Tools -> Build System -> New Build System`

Replace existing code with (NEW):

```
{
    "cmd": ["python3", "-u", "$file"],     
    "file_regex": "^[ ]File \"(...?)\", line ([0-9]*)",     
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

Press `Ctrl + S` / `Cmd + S` to save it with any name you would like (e.g. `MyCustomBuild.sublime-build` - the `.sublime-build` is important). Now that it's saved, go back to `Tools -> Build System -> MyCustomBuild` (or the name you saved as). Let me know in the comments if you still have problems with it. :)

Comment: Don't use `-i`; that tells Python to go interactive and Sublime doesn't support interactive programs unless you're also using a third party package like Terminus, which this build does not. Also as presented there this isn't a valid build because the file doesn't have the `{` and `}` characters; you may want to edit to include them or mention that, since your first line is "Replace", which will break the file.

Comment: @OdatNurd thanks for pointing those out. :)

Comment: I did it with the updated code, saved it as "python3" but can't see it in my build list. Do i have to change the ```\"(...?)\"``` part or really just copy and paste?

Comment: @Skywalker try the new version I posted. It should work right away. Also, try and save the build with a name like "MyCustomBuild" just to be sure it doesn't influence anything else.

Comment: I still can't get it to work. I tried both versions and multiple names to save the file. When saving, it defaults the location to ```C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text\Packages\User\python3.py```. Is this correct?

Comment: @Skywalker save it in the same directory as `python3.sublime-build` and it'll show up in the Build Systems menu.

Comment: I *strongly* recommend against using a build system with the specific file name in it, because it will only work with that particular file. The whole point of a build system in Sublime is that they are generic for any file of the specified type.

Comment: @MattDMo How can i find the directory?

Comment: @Skywalker which directory? The `.sublime-build` file should be saved in `C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text\Packages\User`.